# Exception with git mergetool

Tags: windows, git, merge, mergetool

I'm trying configure meld for windows. 
Just now, I added the python variable environment and the follow steps:

```
git config --global merge.tool meld
git config --global mergetool.meld.path /c/Users/andarno/Downloads/meld-1.5.2/bin/meld
```

But when I try to merge the changes the follow message appears:

```
Normal merge conflict for 'folder/script.js':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (meld):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ben/Desktop/Meld/meld/bin/meld", line 98, in <module>
    libintl = cdll.intl
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 435, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
folder/script.js seems unchanged.
```

I'm not sure the reason of the error, someone has an idea?

Comment: Is this problem specific to just using meld as mergetool, or does it also occur if you use other programs like kdiff3?

Comment: only with meld, kidiff3 is working good. Maybe is a problem related with python

Comment: And if you run `c:\Users\ben\Desktop\Meld\meld\bin\meld` manually from a cmd.exe command prompt you do not get the above error?

Comment: Yes, with a cmd, and as git mergetoolm but always the same error. I'll try updating python